# Show call stack / executed methods without setting breakpoints?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, kotlin, intellij-idea, callstack

Is it possible to record all methods called by my Android app without setting any breakpoint? E.g. if I have no clue where to start, but just want to know which methods are called in my app (and the libraries it uses) during the action I perform by using my app. How could I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/generate-trace-logs

Comment: @Nicolas Didn't test yet, but sounds promising. Will definitely test later! However, as the debugger should have access to all code (in debug mode) I am wondering if it's possible to somehow watch the call stack live from inside Android Studio?

Comment: However this seems like a horrible idea, see [Is it a good practice to log all methods for debugging purpose (for tracing program flow)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436550/is-it-a-good-practice-to-log-all-methods-for-debugging-purpose-for-tracing-prog) The amount of output it'll generate will be incredibly overwhelming unless you somehow specify filters. Android Studio also has a profiler maybe that would be better?

Comment: I do not intent do deliver this kind of tracing to any customer or so. It's just for me, e.g. currently I have a Material Component and I need to know which code is executed once I touch it. I don't even know where to start looking / where I could set the first breakpoint and execute the code step by step. If I would just see which methods were called in my app and the used libraries, I could easily see where to start watching. Do you have more hints about the profiler? I heard of those for memory, cpu etc, yet I am not sure how they would show executed code?

Comment: No the profiler won't help for that actually. Can you tell me which component and what is being touched? Maybe I can help.

Comment: thank. let me check how far the trace logs work as I imagine it. If this does not help I might post a separate question, as it's too much stuff to explain it here in the comments (would then of course link the question here)

Comment: @Nicolas Could meanwhile test with the CPU profiler / method tracing and it indeed helped. The filtering in the CPU profiler, however, is not very good, only graying out stuff instead of hiding it. Guess I have to experiment more with systrace and the tools for viewing systrace to get some better filtering options for the future. Please consider posting your first comment as answer.